# Custom UIPopover has strange shadow on iOS 6

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I am using the `UIPopoverBackgroundView` class to display a custom `UIPopover`.

Here is the thing. On iOS 5, the popover is displayed without dropping any shadows **behind** the popover. However, in iOS 6, the popover drops a very strange shadow that does not perfectly fit the popover:

[image: ios 5 popover]

[image: ios 6 popover]

is there anyway I can control this behavior to reach a consistent look on both versions?

Comment: OK, this is weird. In the example provided, I used a strechable image. Now, I decided to use a `UIView` and set the `backgroundColor` to my custom color, then set it as a subview (instead of the image). Now, the shadow disappeared from ios 6 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to remove the shadow on iOS 6, and add a custom shadow to your popover:

1) remove the shadow by overriding `layoutSubviews`

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    // remove shadow (iOS 6)
}
```

2) Add a shadow property to your BG view

```
_borderView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
_borderView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.f;
_borderView.layer.shadowRadius = 15;
_borderView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);

_borderView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the shadow offset on your UIPopoverBackgroundView layer:

```
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(_leftOffset, 0);
```

Edit: In other words, the shadow is right, just in the wrong place.

Comment: Sorry, Cricket, I don't think you understood the problem well. The shadow was showing up on iOS 6, but never showed up on iOS 5. The position is not the main issue, even though it might be a minor one.

Comment: True, but to anyone stumbling on this question with just the iOS 6 shadow issue (like me), the answer is above.  Just nudge the offset.